# Що таке "поляруш"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Сьогодні на вулиці почула розмову двох старших людей. Жінка сказала до чоловіка: "Миколо, дістань свій поляруш". В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/) цього слова не знайшла. Очевидно, це діалектизм. То що ж таке **поляруш**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Згадку про це слово знайшла у літературному журналі [Київська Русь](http://shron2.chtyvo.org.ua/Kyivska_Rus/2010_N05-06_48-49.pdf):

> В моєму **полярусі** останні десять гривень.

Це наштовхнуло на думку, що слово означає *гаманець*.
Таким чином у [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/132342/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81) знайшла таке:

> **полярис**, -а, ч., ***діал***. **Портмоне; гаманець, капшук**.

Таку ж інформацію знайшла і [тут](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-132320.htm).

На сайті [Спільнота хороших жінок](http://names.neolove.ru/last_names/15/po/poljarush.html) теж натрапила на таке ж трактування значення слово, однак із зазначенням, що походить *від польського слова polares*, однак підтвердження у польських словниках нема.